# Nesting Layouts in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

tl;dr: **is there a clean way to nest layouts in Sinatra?**

For all pages on my site, I have a common layout.erb which renders a header, a footer, and some other bits.

For a subset of those pages, I would like to use an inner layout which renders a left menu in addition to those common bits.

### globally

`erb :pageTemplate` executes layout.erb, where `yield` executes pageTemplate

### in the subset

`erb :pageTemplate` executes layout.erb, where `yield` executes specificLayout.erb, where `yield` executes pageTemplate.

---

make sense?

I am open to separate classes, before statements, and any other ruby magic.  I am not looking for adding header/footer partials and including them in each layout.

Comment: why not just pass in a configuration flag which conditionally includes the left menu? i think it's usually better to err on the side of having dumb views, than to steal control from the controller.

Comment: hey @jacobangel! I think I will end up doing a combination of configuration flags and partials to get the result.  Eventually, there would be several subsets, each with their own left menu, so I didn't want to clutter the main layout too much.  It would just be super cool if a base controller could have a base layout, and all inheriting controllers could have their layout and inherit from the base.  npd if I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 10):

Found it!
http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Templates%20with%20%3Ccode%3Eyield%3C/code%3E%20and%20nested%20layouts

```
erb :site_layout, :layout => false do
  erb :region_layout do
    erb :page
  end
end
```

now, `:site_layout` can contain the header and footer, `:region_layout` can contain left navigation, and `:page` only has to worry about the page content!

Comment: answer to your own question - love it! <3

Answer (score 4):

### globally

```
erb :pageTemplate
```

### in the subset

```
erb :pageTemplate, :layout => :specificLayout
```

---

Edit:

One way is to use partials, either via Erb or [Sinatra Partial](https://github.com/yb66/Sinatra-Partial) (I'm the maintainer, I don't get any money for this advertisment;)

Pass a flag to the layout that affects rendering:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</html>
</head>
<body>
  <%= erb @specificLayout if @specificLayout %>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

in the route:

```
@specificLayout = :left_menu
```

If you new that a whole bunch of routes will want the same flag, then a bit of inheritance will help:

```
# one big config.ru
require 'sinatra/base'

class MainController < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    # lots of shared settings here
    enable :inline_templates
    set :specificLayout, nil
  end

  helpers do
    # all subclasses get these too
    def route
      request.path
    end
  end

  get "/" do
    erb :home
  end
end

class SubWithLeftMenu < MainController
  configure do
    set :specificLayout, :left_menu
  end

  get "/" do
    erb :something
  end
end

map( "/something" ) { run SubWithLeftMenu }
map( "/" ) { run MainController }

__END__

@@ layout

<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Route: <%= route %></p>
  <%= erb settings.specificLayout if settings.specificLayout %>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>

@@ something

<p>Hello!</p>

@@ home

<p>At home</p>

@@ left_menu

<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Running it:

```
$ bin/rackup config.ru &
[1] 40556
[2013-06-21 22:16:34] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1olumes/RubyProjects/Test/nestinglayouts
[2013-06-21 22:16:34] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-02-06) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
[2013-06-21 22:16:34] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=40556 port=9292

$ curl http://localhost:9292/

127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2013 22:16:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 99 0.0399

<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Route: /</p>


<p>At home</p>


</body>
</html>


$ curl http://localhost:9292/something/
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2013 22:16:51] "GET /something/ HTTP/1.1" 200 141 0.0064

<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Route: /something/</p>

<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>

<p>Hello!</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Won't that just use the specificLayout only?  I would like `pageTemplate` wrapped in `specificLayout`, wrapped in `globalLayout`.

Comment: @PatNewell yes. Sorry, that's what I got from your question. I'll have a think about the best way to do it and update my answer. Is there some specific reason you're against partials?

Comment: thanks @iain. no specific reason, the nested layout concept just feels cleaner. I will definitely go with partials if I can't do it this way.

Comment: @PatNewell I've updated the answer with my thoughts on how I might do it.